# Get workstation information from the browser

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, html

Our legacy webforms application is getting workstation and Windows user information through Silverlight control. Is there some HTML5 capability that would allow us to get rid of the plugin? Obviously, if Silverlight is not installed, we get the IP from the request to fall back on.

I know that .NET allows "windows authentication" - so it *is* able to get workstation information somehow. The application is .NET, if it makes a difference, with Angular Front end and Web APIs.

Comment: Can you be more specific? What information are you looking for, exactly? Machine name?  Something more than you get from "windows authentication"?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can't. What information do you need EXACTLY? As in what information are you getting from Silverlight at the moment?

Comment: to quote original post, workstation name and user name (DOMAIN\login name)